# Does there exist a generalized 'ideal gas law' for every pair of thermodynamic variables, e.g. $$ \gamma A = NkT$$ vs $$PV=NkT$$ for surface tension?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Does there exist a generalized 'ideal gas law' for every pair of thermodynamic variables, e.g. $ \gamma A = NkT$ for surface tension?

The first law or thermodynamic relation says:
$$ dE = \delta Q + \delta W$$
$$ dE = T dS - P dV$$

Here $P$ and $V$ are a 'pair'  of thermodynamic variables (this had a specific named that I cannot recollect). The pressure $P$ pushes out a volume $V$ to perform work $\delta W$

This correspond to the ideal gas law: $$ PV = NkT$$

However we can write $ dE = \delta Q + \delta W$ with a 'generalized force':

$$ dE = TdS - \dot pdq $$

Where $\dot p $ is a generalized force $F$ and $q$ is a generalized coordinate of $p$

Then we could write a generalized ideal law:

$$ \dot p q=NkT$$

I don't really know what this says and what it means. For example for the surface tension you can write the first law as:

$$ dE = TdS - \gamma dA$$

Then the 'ideal gas law'  of surface tension would say:

$$ \gamma A = NkT$$

This all probably does not seem right, could help me shed some light on this? Is this possible?

Comment: It's not right, because you can't derive these expressions from the laws of thermodynamics alone. I mean, of course you can't, because that would imply that all gases obey the ideal gas law, which isn't remotely true.

Comment: With some assumptions you can derive the ideal gas law from the first law

Comment: Yeah, but those specific assumptions don't quite hold for real gases, and the analogues of those assumptions for surface tension don't hold at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Statistical Mechanics, the ideal gas is a model where the interparticle potential energy is neglected with respect to the kinetic energy term.

Surface tension appears only as an effect of the different interparticle interactions experienced by particles close to an interface and those in the bulk. Therefore, it is difficult to conceive something like an "ideal gas law" for surface tension, if *ideal* should keep the same meaning as in the case of the ideal gas.

Comment: What about a gaz for which kinetic energy is very weak relative to the inter-particle potential energy?

Comment: @Cham I have a hard time seeing how in gas the kinetic energy could be very weak relative to the inter-particle potential energy.